# Skip numbers in loop in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, for-loop, push, modulo

So I've got the following code:

```
var lowMin      = 01;
var highMin     = 59;

var minuteList  = [];

for (var i = lowMin; i <= highMin; i++) {
    minuteList  .push(i);
}
```

What I want is that between 1 and 59 it creates an array that looks like this:
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30] and so on until 59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you could use `Modulus (%)` i.e `i%5`, simply.

```
// Will evaluate to true if the variable is divisible by 5
variable % 5 === 0 

// Will evaluate to true if the variable is divisible by 2
variable % 2 === 0 

//For your example.
if(i%5 == 0)
{
   minuteList.push(i);
}
```

```js
var lowMin      = 01;
var highMin     = 59;

var minuteList  = [];

for (var i = lowMin; i <= highMin; i++) {
    if(i%5 == 0)
    {
       minuteList.push(i);
    }
}  
console.log(minuteList);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will iterate 80% of the time doing nothing else than modulo testing.

Answer (score 1):

You could let your loop variable take steps of 5, making sure it starts at a multiple of 5:

```js
var lowMin      = 01;
var highMin     = 59;
var minuteList  = [];

for (var i = Math.ceil(lowMin/5)*5; i <= highMin; i+=5) {
  minuteList.push(i);
}

console.log(minuteList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
    var lowMin      = 01;
    var highMin     = 59;
    var step = 5;
    
    var minuteList  = [];
    
    for (var i = step; i <= highMin; i+=step) {
        minuteList  .push(i);
    }
    
    console.log(minuteList);
```